# Why the function is not returning the desired list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return

My code:

```
directions = ["north", "south", "east", "west"]
def scan(sentence):
    global sentence_list
    sentence_list = []
    sentence.split()
    for i in sentence:
        if i in directions:
            a = ('direction', i)
            sentence_list.append(a)
            del a
    return sentence_list
```

I am trying to split a string and return the words in a tuple within a list, but whenever i test it using returns empty list.

Here's my output:

```
PS C:\Users\dell 3521\lpythw\ex48> nosetests
F
======================================================================
FAIL: tests.lexicon_tests.test_directions
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell 3521\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
 32\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.7-py3.6.egg\nose\case.py
    ", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "C:\Users\dell 3521\lpythw\ex48\tests\lexicon_tests.py", line 5, in 
test_directions
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("north"), [('direction', 'north')])
AssertionError: Lists differ: [] != [('direction', 'north')]

Second list contains 1 additional elements.
First extra element 0:
('direction', 'north')

- []
+ [('direction', 'north')]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.021s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly-

Comment: `sentence.split()` does not modify `sentence` in-place.

Comment: You should try using `for i in sentence.split():`

Comment: It is intended in the source file, but i forgot to indent the code post after posting the question.It is rectified now.

Comment: don't use global, `del a` is not necessary, `i` is a bad name for a word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reassign `sentence` to the return value of `sentence.split()` or iterate directly over `sentence.split()`, because the [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method does not modify `sentence` in place, but returns a list instead.

Also you do not need the `del a` statement.

Change your code to

```
directions = ["north", "south", "east", "west"]

def scan(sentence):
    global sentence_list
    sentence_list = []
    for i in sentence.split():
        if i in directions:
            a = ('direction', i)
            sentence_list.append(a)

    return sentence_list
```

Or a even shorter way is using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
directions = ["north", "south", "east", "west"]

def scan(sentence):
    global sentence_list
    sentence_list = [('direction', i) for i in sentence.split() if i in directions]

    return sentence_list
```

The output is

```
>>> scan("north")
[('direction', 'north')]
```

And you may want the over think the use of the `global` statement in your code.
As explained in [various](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/maintainability/using_the_global_statement.html) [resources](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/25jzga/what_exactly_makes_global_variables_so_bad/), you want to avoid using global variables for the readability and maintainability of your code.

Comment: `sentence = sentence.split()` is redundant. `for i in sentence.split():` is sufficient

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was helpful, but i tried, as you suggested, removing del a and it worked. Still, aren't tuples supposed to be immutable.

Comment: Yeah, of course they are. But you create a new tuple every time you call `a = ('direction', i)` in your loop.
 
On the other hand trying to change an element of a, like `a[1] = 'north'` would result in a `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`

Answer (score 0):

The `str.split()` method does not modify the string in-place. You should assign the returning value of `str.split()` to a variable, or in this case, you can simply iterate over it instead:

```
sentence_list = []
for i in sentence.split():
```